# How do I turn colon separated values into comma separated values in python?

Tags: python, string, list, csv

If i have a string of words separated by colons or hyphens what would be the best method of putting them into a list?

```
string = ('car:boat:motorcycle:plane')
```

into

```
list = ['car', 'boat', 'motorcycle', 'plane']
```

Comment: `string.split(':')`

Comment: Thanks i probably should've known that

Answer (score 1):

Use the `split` method and pass the separator

`string.split(":")`

Default separator is any whitespace.

An optional second argument, `maxsplit`, will tell Python to split only that number of times:

`string.split(":", 2)` results in `['car', 'boat', 'motorcycle:plane']`